# Undefined Variable $action

Tags: variables, action, undefined

I have the following two simple scripts. $action being detected as "Not Set". If isset statement is not used, warning "Undefined variable $action" is popped. I don't know what is the problem, please help.

prog01.html :

```
<a href="prog02.php?action='add'">Press to add record</a>
```

prog02.php :

```
<?php
if (isset($action)){  
  if ($action == 'add') echo "action is to add <br>";  
}  
else  
    echo "\$action is not set <br>";  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify that action value is submitted using GET or POST method like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])){  
$action = $_POST['action'];
}  
else if (isset($_GET['action'])){  
$action = $_GET['action'];
}
if ($action == 'add')
{
echo "action is to add <br>";  
}  
else  
{
echo "\$action is not set <br>"; 
}
?>
```